# Extending a Generic type where T has another Generic Type

Tags: swift, generics

I have a data model that I use to parse json coming from an API.

```
struct APIResult<Result> {
    public let result: Result?
    ...
}
```

This object accepts different result types and I extend it so I can have custom initializers with different logics in it so that my `APIService` will not have any boilerplate code.

These are examples of the extensions that I do so that the initializers would look the same

```
extension APIResult where Result: SomeClass  {
    init(_ json: Any, resultType: Result.Type) {
        ...
    }
}

extension APIResult where Result == SomeStruct  {
    init(_ json: Any, resultType: Result.Type) {
        ...
    }
}

// which then would look like this on the request function somewhere

request.warpResponse {
    completion(APIResult($0, resultType: UserProfile.self))
}
```

Now I have a problem when I try to extend `APIResult` to an object with its own generic say for example `Array<Element>`, when I try to create the extension it would definitely look like this

```
extension APIResult where Result == Array<SomeClass>  {
    init(_ json: Any, resultType: Result.Type) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But then when I try to initialize

```
// here's a subclass of SomeClass 
class SubClass: SomeClass { ... }

request.warpResponse {
    completion(APIResult($0, resultType: Array< SubClass >.self))
    // or
    completion(APIServiceResult($0, resultType: [SubClass].self))
}
```

An error message would appear saying

> Cannot convert value of type 'Array< SubClass >.Type' to expected argument type 'Array< SomeClass>.Type'

or

> Cannot convert value of type '[SubClass].Type' to expected argument type 'Array< SomeClass >.Type'

Is there a way to fix this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a protocol in place of `Array<SomeClass>` and make the `Array` conform to that protocol in case of its `Element` is `SomeClass` type.

Something like this:

```
struct APIResult<Result> {
    public let result: Result?
}

protocol SomeProtocol { }

class SomeClass { }

class SubClass: SomeClass {   }

extension APIResult where Result: SomeProtocol  {
    init(_ json: Any, resultType: Result.Type) {
        result = nil
    }
}

extension Array: SomeProtocol where Element: SomeClass {

}

APIResult("", resultType: Array<SubClass>.self)
```